# build.gradle access public variable from another class -- manifest placeholders

Tags: java, android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

Let's say I have `MyClass.java` which has `public public static final String myString = new ObfuscatedString(---);`.

Is it possible to access that value in `build.gradle`? I want to continue using the obfuscated string which is already in use elsewhere to avoid putting the value in plaintext.

Here is an example of what I have tried with no success:

`manifestPlaceholders = [myValue: myClass.MyString]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it possible to access that value in build.gradle?

No.

You are welcome to have a value in Gradle that you use in `manifestPlaceholders` and `buildConfigField`, to expose the same value in both places. But Gradle, not Java, is the starting point.

Comment: This is a value that I don't want to leave in plaintext in gradle. It's unfortunate that there doesn't seem to be any kind of workaround for this issue.

Comment: @Jake_: "This is a value that I don't want to leave in plaintext in gradle" -- I didn't say to store it in plain text in Gradle. That would be one possibility. Other possibilities include `gradle.properties`, environment variables, anything that you can do in Groovy (which, by extension, means anything that you can do in Java SE), or the output of other command-line tools (captured into a Gradle variable).